# How to reverse an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I need to reverse my content list. I found `Collections.reverse(temp);`, but don't know how to implement it right.

```
private class MyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Advice> results = new ArrayList<Advice>();

        if (orig == null)
            orig = list;

        if (constraint != null) {
            if (orig != null) {
                for (Advice d : orig) {
                    if ((d.getTitle() + " " + d.getText()).toLowerCase()
                            .contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        results.add(d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        list = results;

        return oReturn;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of collection have using ?

Comment: Do you have a collection (Array list for ex). Did you trying use `Collections.reverse(list);`?

Comment: atleast post your list code.

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use `Collections.reverse()`. That *is* the normal way to reverse a collection, so show us how you tried to use it and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
  // Create the list
  ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

  // Add some items to it
  myList.add("one");
  myList.add("two");
  myList.add("three");

  // Reverse it by using Collections utilities.
  Collections.reverse(myList);

  Log.i("DEBUG", myList.get(0)); // Should print 'three'
```

Comment: it dont work, only if i go to the POST  and then click Return. Show please where i should use it in my code. Thanks

Comment: This is up to you. You're asking about your application specific code. My answer does exactly what you asked for. We do not know what is "POST" or "return"

Answer (score 1):

You should import

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

and then use

```
Collections.reverse(results);
```

Comment: it dont work, only if i go to the POST  and then click Return. Show please where i should use it in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the elements matching the criteria and you don't have java8 or any functional lib, you can either reverse it after the construction loop, or reverse the original before traversing. Or just traverse it in reverse order during construction. An example with using indexes:

```
for(int i = orig.size()-1; i >-1; i--) {
    //add matching elements to the newly constructed list.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below:
private class MyFilter extends Filter {

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

    FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
    ArrayList<Advice> results = new ArrayList<Advice>();

    if (orig == null)
        orig = list;

    if (constraint != null) {
        if (orig != null) {
            for (Advice d : orig) {
                if ((d.getTitle() + " " + d.getText()).toLowerCase()
                        .contains(constraint.toString())) {
                    results.add(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.reverse(results);
    oReturn.values = results;
    oReturn.count = results.size();

    return oReturn;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
        FilterResults results) {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

the best way in parser add:

```
Collections.reverse(data);
System.out.println(data.toString());
```